# How can we improve the gzip compression performance ,can any one help me on this

Tags: scala

I merged the files into single file using fileutils and i compressed the file into GZIP,i have very big file to compress it's taking long time to compress.how can i improve the performance in GZIP.
here is sample code.

```
 def gzFile(fs:FileSystem, inputFile: String, outputFile: String) {
    val fIS = fs.open(new Path(inputFile))
    val fOS = fs.create(new Path(outputFile))
    val gZipOS = new GZIPOutputStream(fOS);
    copyData(fIS, gZipOS)
  }
```

Comment: Try using a parallel GZIP API like [Parallel GZIP](https://github.com/shevek/parallelgzip)

Comment: will parallel Gzip  work of scala as well

Comment: As that is implemented in Java, and Scala has interoperability with Java codes, it should work!